# Can not get logs of Kubernetes K8S pod (to debug)

Tags: kubernetes, nodes, kube-proxy

I have 1 master and 2 nodes running and kube-proxy to debug.

```
kube-m1:/$ kubectl get pod -n kube-system kube-proxy-tmt58
NAME               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-proxy-tmt58   1/1     Running   6          439d
```

How can I specify a namespace to get `kubectl logs` to debug a pod?

```
kube-m1:/$ kubectl logs kube-proxy-tmt58
Error from server (NotFound): pods "kube-proxy-tmt58" not found
```

I am new in kubernetes so, also would be great and very helpful to get some good and working guides or materials about pods and nodes debugging :)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Just like you did it to get a pod, to specify a namespace you can pass `-n` | `--namespace` flag, so your command would look like

```
kubectl logs kube-proxy-tmt58 -n kube-system
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @jabbson answer I only want to mention and recommend you to save into the bookmarks [kubectl Cheat Sheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/). This page has huge amount of kubectl usage examples. It will help you a lot to deep into kubernetes world.

```
# Get commands with basic output
kubectl get services                          # List all services in the namespace
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces             # List all pods in all namespaces
kubectl get pods -o wide                      # List all pods in the current namespace, with more details
kubectl get deployment my-dep                 # List a particular deployment
kubectl get pods                              # List all pods in the namespace
kubectl get pod my-pod -o yaml                # Get a pod's YAML

# Describe commands with verbose output
kubectl describe nodes my-node
kubectl describe pods my-pod

# Get all worker nodes (use a selector to exclude results that have a label
# named 'node-role.kubernetes.io/master')
kubectl get node --selector='!node-role.kubernetes.io/master'

# Get all running pods in the namespace
kubectl get pods --field-selector=status.phase=Running

# Get ExternalIPs of all nodes
kubectl get nodes -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.addresses[?(@.type=="ExternalIP")].address}'

# Logs
kubectl logs my-pod                                 # dump pod logs (stdout)
kubectl logs -l name=myLabel                        # dump pod logs, with label name=myLabel (stdout)
kubectl logs my-pod --previous                      # dump pod logs (stdout) for a previous instantiation of a container
kubectl logs my-pod -c my-container                 # dump pod container logs (stdout, multi-container case)
kubectl logs -l name=myLabel -c my-container        # dump pod logs, with label name=myLabel (stdout)
kubectl logs my-pod -c my-container --previous      # dump pod container logs (stdout, multi-container case) for a previous instantiation of a container
kubectl logs -f my-pod                              # stream pod logs (stdout)
kubectl logs -f my-pod -c my-container              # stream pod container logs (stdout, multi-container case)
kubectl logs -f -l name=myLabel --all-containers    # stream all pods logs with label name=myLabel (stdout)
```